# How to get number of days(intersection) between two date ranges/Count of days intersecting between two date ranges in Javascript/Moment

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, momentjs

TotalStartDate: 01/28 TotalEndDate: 02/22

and I have array of dates like

DATA:

```
StartDate2:01/27 endDate2:02/02
StartDate2:02/03 endDate2:02/09
StartDate2:02/10 endDate2:02/16
StartDate2:02/17 endDate2:02/23


dateRanges=[
{"startDate":01/27,"EndDate":02/02}
{"startDate":02/03,"EndDate":02/09}
{"startDate":02/10,"EndDate":02/16}
{"startDate":02/17,"EndDate":02/23}
]
```

now I need to get no  days matched a  data range in the initial date range

[0] index data range is starting from 01/27 and TotalStartDate is from 01/28 so 1 day is wasted and only 6 days should get as count

[1] index data range is starting from 02/03 and  TotalStartDate is from 01/28 All dates of [1] index data range come inside the TotalStartDate and TotalEndDate so count should be 7

[2] count 7

[3] count 6 as enddate is more than totalEndDate .

Comment: Please post the exact array for clarity

Answer (score 3):

Is this something you are looking for?

Algorithm we can use to achieve this:

- lets consider we have dateRanges array, inputStartDate, inputEnddate as inputs.
- We have to iterate thrugh our dateRanges array so that we can calculate days based on conditions.
- Lets calculate which start date to consider( is it startDate from array or the inputed start date. In the same way, we need to identify which endDate to consider.
- Finally, as we received the start dates and end dates to consider, we can simply calculate difference between the two dates.

Below is the code for the same.

I have my dateRanges array, inputStartDate, inputEnddate and my logic to calcuate Days between the inputed range as below:

```
let dateRanges=[
{"startDate":"01/27","EndDate":"02/02"},
{"startDate":"02/03","EndDate":"02/09"},
{"startDate":"02/10","EndDate":"02/16"},
{"startDate":"02/17","EndDate":"02/23"}
]
let inputStartDate = "01/28"

let inputEndDate = "02/22"

dateRanges.forEach(eachDate => {
    var endDateToConsider = moment(eachDate.EndDate+'/2019').isAfter(inputEndDate+"/2019") ? inputEndDate: eachDate.EndDate;
    var startDateToConsider = moment(eachDate.startDate+'/2019').isAfter(inputStartDate+"/2019") ? eachDate.startDate : inputStartDate
    var daysDifference = moment(endDateToConsider+'/2019').diff(moment(startDateToConsider+'/2019'), 'days') + 1
    console.log(daysDifference)

})
```